# Relation between a matrix and transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

A $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is a linear transformation from the space of $ n \times n$ matrices to itself. What is the $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix corresponding to this transformation? If we knew the nullity and rank of $A$, how could we find the nullity and rank for this transformation?

P.S: I can not even understand the question, let alone the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ denote the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices with real entries. A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ specifices a *linear* map $\phi_A : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ through matrix matrix multipliciation, i.e
\begin{equation}
\forall X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \: : \: \phi_A(X) = AX.
\end{equation}
By definition, $\phi_A(X) = AX$ can be computed by computing $Ax_i$ for each column vector $x_i$ of $X$. If we where to stack the columns of $X$ on top of each other, forming the gigantic vector $\tilde{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ given by
\begin{equation}
\tilde{x} = (x_1^T, x_2^T, \cdot, x_n^T)^T
\end{equation}
and wanted to obtain a a similar representation of $Y = AX$, this could be achieved through the matrix vector multiplication 
\begin{equation}
\tilde{y} = \tilde{A} \tilde{x}
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ is obtained by using $n$ copies of $A$ as diagonal blocks in a gigantic matrix, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\tilde{A} = \begin{pmatrix} A & & & \\  & A & & \\ & & \ddots & \\ & & & A \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
This form reveals that if $A$ has rank $r$, then $\tilde{A}$ has rank $nr$.

There is good mathematical notation for the objects that I have used here. Normally, one writes
\begin{equation}
\tilde{x} = \text{vec}(X)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\tilde{A} = I_n \otimes A
\end{equation}
where $I_n$ is the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.